# Getting the next element in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Let's say I have a list of index positions:

```
index_position = [1,3,5]
```

And a dataframe such as this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
```

What I'm trying to do is iterate through the list and add the element location in the `df` to the next element location in the `df`, in a fashion similar to this:

```
for i in index_position:
    sum = df['A'].iloc[i] + df['A'].iloc[i+1]
    print(sum)
```

Which would result in it printing `4` and `8`. Of course `i+1` unfortunately doesn't give me the next element in the list, it quite literally adds 1 to the element.

Comment: why do you use .iloc instead of `df['A'][i]`, or in your case `df['A'][i+1]`

Comment: I am getting `3 7 11` as the answer

Comment: Hi thanks for everyone's answers, I'm obviously not asking the correct question though. Firstly I use .iloc because every time I don't I get an error message telling me to use .iloc, in this case however I don't, not sure why. Secondly, if we take the index position of 1 in the df we see it corresponds to the number 1, the next element in the list is 3, and this corresponds to the number 3 in the df at that index position. 1 + 3 is 4. The next sum should be 8, and as there is no element beyond the 3rd one I should not get a third answer as there is no 4th element to add to the 3rd.

Comment: I don't want to just do element + 1, I want the next element in the list.

Comment: Strictly, this question and the accepted answer (using `pd.DataFrame.rolling`) are about pandas DataFrames, not Python lists. There are other existing Q&A for Python lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`pd.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
>>> print(*df.loc[index_position, 'A'].rolling(2).sum().dropna(), sep='\n')
4.0
8.0
```

For a different data:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(0,30,3)})
>>> df
    A
0   0
1   3
2   6
3   9
4  12
5  15
6  18
7  21
8  24
9  27

>>> index_position = [1, 3, 5]

>>> print(*df.loc[index_position,'A'].rolling(2).sum().dropna(), sep='\n')
12.0
24.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this be enough?

```
sum = df['A'][i] + df['A'][i+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `enumerate` through a list to get the index (or a running count).

```
for count, index in enumerate(index_position):
    print('count: ', count)
    print('index: ', index)
```

This will result in:

```
>> count: 0
>> index: 1

>> count: 1
>> index: 3

>> count: 2
>> index: 5
```